# Are these valid proofs for the equation $\gcd(n,\sigma(n^2))=\gcd(n^2,\sigma(n^2))$, if $q^k n^2$ is an odd perfect number with special prime $q$?

Tags: solution-verification, gcd-and-lcm, divisor-sum, arithmetic-functions, perfect-numbers

Let $N = q^k n^2$ be an [odd perfect number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_number#Odd_perfect_numbers) with special prime $q$ satisfying $q \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$.

It is [known](https://nntdm.net/volume-23-2017/number-2/12-20/) that
$$i(q)=\gcd(n^2,\sigma(n^2))=\frac{\sigma(n^2)}{q^k}=\frac{n^2}{\sigma(q^k)/2},$$
where $i(q)$ is the *index* of the odd perfect number $N$ at the prime $q$.

Consider the quantity $\gcd(n,\sigma(n^2))$.  Trivially,
$$\gcd(n,\sigma(n^2)) \mid \gcd(n^2,\sigma(n^2))$$
holds since $n \mid n^2$ is true.

> Want to show: $\gcd(n,\sigma(n^2)) = \gcd(n^2,\sigma(n^2))$

---

**MY PROOF ATTEMPT #1**

First, we write $n$ as
$$n = i(q)\cdot\frac{\sigma(q^k)}{2n}.$$
Next, we express $\sigma(n^2)$ as
$$\sigma(n^2) = i(q)\cdot{q^k}.$$
Thus, the GCD of $n$ and $\sigma(n^2)$ is given by
$$\gcd(n,\sigma(n^2))=\gcd\left(i(q)\cdot\frac{\sigma(q^k)}{2n},i(q)\cdot{q^k}\right)=i(q)\cdot\gcd\left(\frac{\sigma(q^k)}{2n},q^k\right)=i(q)\cdot{1}=i(q)=\gcd(n^2,\sigma(n^2)),$$
since, in general, $\gcd(\sigma(q^k),q^k) = 1$ holds.

**QED**

---

**MY PROOF ATTEMPT #2**

Similar to the argument in *Proof Attempt #1*, we obtain
$$\gcd(n,\sigma(n^2))=i(q)\cdot\gcd\left(\frac{\sigma(q^k)}{2n},q^k\right).$$

Consequently, we have the divisibility condition
$$i(q)=\gcd(n^2,\sigma(n^2)) \mid \gcd(n,\sigma(n^2)).$$

Together with the divisibility constraint
$$\gcd(n,\sigma(n^2)) \mid \gcd(n^2,\sigma(n^2))$$
and because of the fact that $\gcd(n,\sigma(n^2))$ and $\gcd(n^2,\sigma(n^2))$ are both positive, then it follows that
$$\gcd(n,\sigma(n^2)) = \gcd(n^2,\sigma(n^2)).$$

---

Here then is my question:

> Are these valid proofs for the equation $\gcd(n,\sigma(n^2))=\gcd(n^2,\sigma(n^2))$, if $N = q^k n^2$ is an odd perfect number with special prime $q$?  If not, how can they be mended so as to produce correct arguments?

Comment: The equation you have written for gcd(n, sigma(n^2)) in proof attempt number 1 seems to assume that gcd(i(q),n)=1. If gcd(i(q),n)>1, then that means i(q) and n share a common factor greater than 1 and hence the expression i(q).sigma(q^k)/2n can be reduced further. If this expression can reduced further then your equation does not hold. However if gcd(i(q),n)=1, then the expression i(q).sigma(q^k)/2n cannot be reduced any further and hence your equation holds. Therefore your equation holds on condition that gcd(i(q),n)=1

Comment: @User4576283:  Following the hint in your [last comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4540847/are-these-valid-proofs-for-the-equation-gcdn-sigman2-gcdn2-sigman2?noredirect=1#comment9552209_4540847), then if $\gcd(i(q),n)=1$, the equation $\gcd(n,\sigma(n^2))=\gcd(n^2,\sigma(n^2))$ holds.  But $\gcd(i(q),n)=\gcd(\gcd(\sigma(n^2),n^2),n)=\gcd(\sigma(n^2),\gcd(n^2,n))=\gcd(n,\sigma(n^2))$.  (continued)

Comment: @User4576283: (continued)  So now, suppose to the contrary that $\gcd(i(q),n)=1$.  It follows that $1=\gcd(n,\sigma(n^2))=\gcd(n^2,\sigma(n^2))=\frac{\sigma(n^2)}{q^k}$, which contradicts the result $\sigma(n^2)/q^k \geq 3$ from [Dris (JIS, 2012)](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL15/Dris/dris8.html).  Thus, $\gcd(i(q),n) > 1$ is true.

Comment: @User4576283: I hereby invite you to write out your comment into a full answer, and add my findings as needs be, so that I may be able to upvote and then accept it!  =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am writing out the answer at the invitation of O.P.

The equation you have written for $\gcd(n, \sigma(n^2))$ in proof attempt number 1 seems to assume that $\gcd(i(q),n)=1$. If $\gcd(i(q),n)>1$, then that means $i(q)$ and $n$ share a common factor greater than $1$ and hence the expression $i(q) \times \sigma(q^k)/{2n}$ can be reduced further. If this expression can be reduced further then your equation does not hold. However, if $\gcd(i(q),n)=1$ then the expression $i(q) \times \sigma(q^k)/{2n}$ cannot be reduced any further and hence your equation holds. Therefore your equation holds on the condition that $\gcd(i(q),n)=1$.

Postscript

The O.P. has proven in the comment section that $\gcd(i(q),n)>1$.